# Solving an equation $x(x-1)(x-1) = 0.063$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x(x-1)(x-1) = 0.063.$ I want to know how this equation gives $0.7$ as an answer. Can somebody help if I solve $(x-1)^2 = 0.063$ I get two answers $1.25$ and $0.7$ , I only take $0.7$ as question was related to probability but what about the first $x$ in this equation?

Comment: If you solve $(x-1)^2=0.063$, you are solving an equation that has little connection with the actual equation $x(x-1)^2=0.063$. And  $0.7$ is not a root of $(x-1)^2=0.063$, the small root is about $0.749$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $0.063=\frac{63}{1000}=\frac{7\cdot 3^2}{1000}$. 
We want to factor this into two factors, one of which is squared (namely the $x-1$ factor). We cannot use the $7$ in the squared factor as it would then contribute a factor of $7^2$ going against the factorization of $0.063$ above.

This suggests taking $x=7/10$, for which $x-1=-3/10$, so that $(x-1)^2=3^2/100$ and it works.

Comment: Thanks that's a genius method by a genius . Hats off :)

Answer (score 2):

$x(x-1)(x-1)=0.063$ has $0.7$ as an answer because
$0.7(0.7-1)(0.7-1)=0.7 \times -0.3 \times -0.3 = 0.063$, as you can verify yourself.

If you mean "how do I find the solution $0.7$ in the first place", there's no easy way in general. For example, the only real solution to $x(x-1)(x-1)=3$ is a horrible mess of radicals. But for this particular equation, $0.7$ shouldn't be too hard to find with guess-and-check.

Comment: Good i found it by hit and trial as well but i wanted to teach someone as to how to reach at 0.7 at first place . Which was getting very difficult to teach :)

Answer (score 0):

$$x(x-1)^2=.063$$
$$x(x^2-2x+1)=.063$$
$$x^3-2x^2+x-.063=0$$
Well this doe not look very nice.  Just use a calculator or [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) to simplify.

In the end you get x=1.2.., x=.7 or x=.07..

Comment: If you have a polynomial of order 3, you should have 3 solutions

Comment: This one has a double root.